# Rolagem de página personalizada

Tags: html, jquery, css

Como posso conseguir construir um efeito de rolagem semelhante a deste site?

http://www.ever.ag/

E como fazer o efeito de "aparecimento" (`fade in`, movimentação) dos objetos?

Comment: Cara  vc pode usar o http://scrollmagic.io/ para fazer isso, repare que a animação acontece enquanto vc vai dando o Scroll, se vc rolar de vagar vai reparar que a cada pequeno scroll ele muda a classe dos elementos. E a navegação vc faz por ancoras e esconde o Scroll original da janela do browser por css. Da pra fazer com JS puro sem plugin tb não é tão complicado pra que já manja de js ou jquery

Comment: A sugestão do @hugocsl é boa! Recomendo também o https://scrollrevealjs.org :)